# Rotating a ImageView having one end fixed in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a Ui which has a look & feel like a speedometer of vehicle which has a needle which is fixed from one end & rotate with some angle with that fixed end.
I have done some sort of code for that

```
self.SIV_Needle.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat(M_PI_2)/180.0) * 80)
```

Its working but the imageView loss its original x & y coordinates from one end.I have tried lot of things like changing anchor point , center but doesn't seems to work well.[image: I want to move that needle]

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you are trying to ask.  What do you mean by 'loss its original x & y coordinates from one end"? Is the issue just that it is not rotating around the axis you want it to rotate around?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel yes , the issue is its not rotating around the axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responding to my comment, OP said the issue was that the control was not rotating around the desired axis.  OP was not (I think) clear about what the desired axis is, nor about what the current axis is (I am using axis interchangeably to mean pivot point).  There are a few potential fixes.

1) This needle thing is an ImageView, so you could do a simple hack and just make your image bigger or smaller to fix the rotation.  To explain: if your needle is rotating around the center of the needle and not the ball part, then simply double the width of the image, such that the needle only takes up the right side and thus the "ball" of the needle is the pivot point.

2) Set the anchor property of the transform to wherever you want it to be rotating around. See [this similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815263/setting-a-rotation-point-for-cgaffinetransformmakerotation-swift) SO question & answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate the UI , to compensate the position change comes due to roatation

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the anchor point of the needle imageView and then add the Rotation. I have not tried it, but i think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this by putting your pin image in a UIView at desired position and rotating your main UIView.

like;

```
let myView:UIIView = UIIView(); //set frame of UIView
let pinImgView:UIVImageView(); // set pin image and frame of required position
//--
myView.addSubview(pinImgView);
//--
myView.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat(M_PI_2)/180.0) * 80);
```

I have made a sample project for this. you can take idea from it;
http://www.filedropper.com/stackover
or
http://wikisend.com/download/263926/StackOver.zip