# How to rotate a Button around a point or the center of a UIView in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, object, button, rotation

I don't want the button to rotate, I want it to revolve around a point, just like Earth rotates around the sun.
To be noted that I barely have a great knowledge in xcode or swift. So I would suggest a simplest form of code, maybe in the form of function so that I can use it to rotate any number of buttons, around a particular point!

Comment: you should give a minimal working example. This helps peolpe answer your question quickly and understand your point properly. You find more information here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a rotation point for CGAffineTransformMakeRotation Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815263/setting-a-rotation-point-for-cgaffinetransformmakerotation-swift)

Comment: The word you are looking for is *revolve*. The Earth *revolves* around the Sun and rotates on its axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at earth and sun, there is no rotation involved: The letter "E" (the earth) will never rotate, e.g. the "north pole" will always point to the same direction. Anti-clockwise rotation looks like this:

```
                 E            
         =>      |     => 
S-E              S          E-S
```

(letter "E" is not rotated).

To do this, your animation will have to follow a circle around the sun.
Create a view controller with two buttons (sunButton and earthButton), and upon touching the sun, the rotation will start or stop:

```
// some helper extension
extension CGPoint {
    static func distanceBetween(point p1: CGPoint,
                                andPoint p2: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(pow((p2.x - p1.x), 2) + pow((p2.y - p1.y), 2))
    }

    static func angle(from fromPoint: CGPoint, to toPoint: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        let dx: CGFloat = fromPoint.x - toPoint.x
        let dy: CGFloat = fromPoint.y - toPoint.y
        let radians: CGFloat = atan2(dy, dx)
        return radians
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sunButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var earthButton: UIButton!

    var isRevolving = false

    @IBAction func sunPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if (!isRevolving) {
            startRevolving()
        } else {
            stopRevolving()
        }
    }

    func startRevolving() {
        isRevolving = true
        let sunCenter = sunButton.center
        let earthCenter = earthButton.center

        let distance = CGPoint.distanceBetween(point: sunCenter, andPoint: earthCenter)
        var angle = CGPoint.angle(from: sunCenter, to: earthCenter)
        angle = .pi + angle

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: sunCenter, radius: distance, startAngle: angle + .pi*2, endAngle: angle, clockwise: false)
        // for clockwise rotation, use:
        //let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: sunCenter, radius: distance, startAngle: angle, endAngle: angle + .pi*2, clockwise: true)

        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.position))
        animation.duration = 5
        animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT
        animation.path = circlePath.cgPath

        earthButton.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    }

    func stopRevolving() {
        isRevolving = false
        if let currentPosition = earthButton.layer.presentation()?.position {
            earthButton.center = currentPosition
        }
        earthButton.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please explain using codes how to achieve that?

Comment: What do you want? The first revolution, or the second rotation with anchorPoint?

Comment: The first revolution!

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. But i'm having difficulty in revolving more than 1 button. Is there any way possible way of creating a function called revolution and when you call it, you can put any amount of buttons inside the argument of function so that everyone revolves around the same point, in their own positions.
Briefly, creating a solar system ! :p

Comment: I would create an extension to `UIButton` with a`revolve` function (which takes two parameters for the center point and the speed) and a `stopRevolve` function which then stops it. Do you need more help?

Answer (score 1):

You can make an extension of a button as below to rotate any instance of button.

```
extension UIButton {

    func rotate(angle: CGFloat) {
        let radians = angle / 180.0 * CGFloat(Double.pi)
        self.transform = self.transform.rotated(by: radians);
    }
}

// Call to rotate button as below from wherever you require in your code
let myButton = UIButton()
myButton.rotate(angle: 180)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am very much looking for a similar simple code but rotation is not what I'm looking for. As one of the comment suggested, maybe I framed the question wrong.
I want the button to revolve, rather than rotate, around a point! Just like Earth revolves around the sun. Consider, Earth as the button & sun as any reference point(maybe the center of a UIView), and the button should revolve around that center point.