# Why does CGAffineTransform(scaleX:y:) cause my view to rotate as if I'd called CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

I took Paul Hudson's (Hacking with Swift) animation tutorial (His Project 15) and tried to extend it to see the effect of multiple animations layered on one another.

There are four distinct animations: scale, translate, rotate and color. Instead of a single button that cycles through all of them, as in his tutorial, I used four buttons to allow selection of each animation individually. I also modified his "undo" animation by reversing the original animation rather than using CGAffineTransform.identity, since the identity transform would undo all the animations to that point.

My problem is that when I click my c button, it does the appropriate scaling the first click but, rather than scale the penguin back to its original size on the second click, it rotates the view. Subsequent clicks of the scale button continue to rotate the view as if I were clicking the rotate button.

There are other anomalies, such as the first click of the move button moves the penguin appropriately but following that with a click of the rotate button, both rotates the penguin and moves it back to the original position. I'm not sure why it moves back but I accept that that might be my own ignorance of the animation system.

I've added print statements and put in breakpoints to debug the scale problem. Everything in the code seems to be working exactly as coded but the animations defy logic! Any help would be appreciated.

The complete program is relatively simple:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var imageView: UIImageView!
    var scaled = false
    var moved = false
    var rotated = false
    var colored = false
    
    @IBOutlet var scaleButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var moveButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var rotateButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var colorButton: UIButton!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "penguin"))
        imageView.center = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 332)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    @IBAction func tapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isHidden = true
        var theAnimation: ()->Void
        
        switch sender {
        case scaleButton:
            theAnimation = scaleIt
        case moveButton:
            theAnimation = moveIt
        case rotateButton:
                theAnimation = rotateIt
        case colorButton:
                theAnimation = colorIt
        default:
            theAnimation = { self.imageView.transform = .identity }
        }
        print("scaled = \(scaled), moved = \(moved), rotated = \(rotated), colored = \(colored)")
    
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [], animations: theAnimation) { finished in
            sender.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    
    func scaleIt() {
        print("scaleIt()")
        let newScale: CGFloat = self.scaled ? -1.5 : 1.5
        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: newScale, y: newScale)
        self.scaled.toggle()
    }
    
    func moveIt() {
        print("moveIt()")
        let newX: CGFloat = self.moved ? 0 : -50
        let newY: CGFloat = self.moved ? 0 : -150
        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: newX, y: newY)
        self.moved.toggle()
    }
    
    func rotateIt() {
        print("rotateIt()")
        let newAngle = self.rotated ? 0.0 : CGFloat.pi
        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: newAngle)
        self.rotated.toggle()
    }
    
    func colorIt() {
        print("colorIt()")
        let newAlpha: CGFloat = self.colored ? 1 : 0.1
        let newColor = self.colored ? UIColor.clear : UIColor.green
        self.imageView.alpha = newAlpha
        self.imageView.backgroundColor = newColor
        self.colored.toggle()
    }
    
}
```

By any combination of clicking the buttons, I can only arrive at 10 configurations of the Penguin (five with CGAffineTransforms and the same five modified by the color button).

I'll use these images to answer some of your questions. I've tried to label these images "Configuration1A, Configuration2A, ...  Configuration1B", where the B configurations are identical to the A configurations but with the color button's effect. Perhaps the labels will show up in my post (I'm very new to posting on StackOverflow).

Here are the five configurations with the first one repeated using the color button:

[image: Configuration1A]

[image: Configuration2A]

[image: Configuration3A]

[image: Configuration4A]

[image: Configuration5A]

[image: Configuration1B (same as 1A but with color button)]

I first tried repeated button pressings. For each series of pressing a given button, I first returned the penguin to its original position, size, angle and color. For these repeated button pressings, the behavior I observed was as follows:

Button  Observed behavior

1. scale   Penguin scales from Configuration1A to Configuration2A (as expected).
2. scale   Penguin rotates by pi from Configuration2A to Configuration4A (WHAT???).
3. scale   Penguin rotates by pi from Configuration4A to Configuration2A (WHAT???).

scale   ...  steps 2 and 3, above, repeat indefinitely (WHAT???).

4. move    Penguin moves (-50, -150), Configuration1A to Configuration3A (as expected).
5. move    Penguin moves (50, 150) Configuration3A to Configuration1A (as expected).
6. move    ...  behavior above repeats indefinitely (as expected).
7. rotate  Penguin rotates by pi, Configuration1A to Configuration5A (as expected).
8. rotate  Penguin rotates by pi, Configuration5A to Configuration1A (as expected).
9. rotate  ...  behavior above repeats indefinitely (as expected).
10. color  Penguin's color changes, Configuration1A to Configuration1B (as expected).
11. color  Penguin's color changes, Configuration1B to Configuration1A   (as expected).
12. color  ...  behavior above repeats indefinitely (as expected).

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site! This is a really well asked question, especially for a newcomer! Could you add some screenshots to help illustrate the buttons and the behaviour they cause?

Comment: The fundamental issue here is that on every button press you’re overwriting the current transformation matrix with a new one, rather than combining the two.

Comment: For scale you have to set this condition ```self.scaled ? 1 : 1.5``` there is no meaning -1.5 here also for rotation you should need to change frame with rotation.https://stackoverflow.com/a/26815851/14733292

Comment: @Alexander, Regarding your first comment, thank you. I'm new to Swift, iOS and StackOverflow but I'm retired from 50 years of programming so I know a little about these things. :-)

Comment: For your second comment, this was exactly the kind of information that I was trying to tease out with my changes to Paul Hudson's sample project. However, the experiment seems to contradict your assertion. The changes, except for scale, seem to stack on one another.

Comment: @RajaKishan The statement `let newScale: CGFloat = self.scaled ? -1.5 : 1.5` uses the standard Swift Ternary Conditional Operator and self.scaled is a boolean. If self.scaled's value is true, newScale is set to -1.5, otherwise, newScale is set to 1.5. This is legitimate Swift code and works as intended.

 Regarding your second comment, I intended my rotations to revolve around the center of the image so I saw no need to reset the anchor point.

Comment: @jwalk I just saying that use 1 scale instead of -1.5 . There is no issue in ternary operator

Comment: It doesn't rotate it. It flips it. There's a big differencxe!

Comment: Nice job expanding your question with more details and sample images (voted).

Comment: @matt, flipping on both X and Y and rotating 180 degrees have the same outcome though, so looking from the outside it's easy to get confused.

Comment: No they don't have the same outcome

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of scale 1.5 (50% bigger) is not -1.5, it's 0.5. (50% of it's original size)

Actually, wouldn't you want it to alternate between a scale of 1.5 (50% bigger) and 1.0 (normal size?)

Assuming you **do** want to alternate between 50% bigger and 50% smaller, change your scaleIt function to:

```
func scaleIt() {
    print("scaleIt()")
    let newScale: CGFloat = self.scaled ? -1.5 : 0.5
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: newScale, y: newScale)
    self.scaled.toggle()
}
```

When you set the X or Y scale to a negative number, it inverts the coordinates in that dimension. Inverting in both dimensions will appear like a rotation.

As somebody else mentioned, the way you've written your functions, you won't be able to combine the different transforms. You might want to rewrite your code to apply the changes to the view's existing transform:

```
func scaleIt() {
    print("scaleIt()")
    // Edited to correct the math if you are applying a scale to an existing transform
    let scaleAdjustment: CGFloat = self.scaled ? -1.5 : 0.66666
    self.imageView.transform = self.imageView.transform.scaledBy(x: scaleAdjustment, y: scaleAdjustment)
    self.scaled.toggle()
}
```

### Edit:

Note that changes to transforms are not "commutative", which is a fancy way of saying that the order in which you apply them matters. Applying a shift, then a rotate, will give different results than applying a rotate, then a shift, for example.

### Edit #2:

Another thing:

The way you've written your functions, they will set the view to its current state, and then invert that current state for next time (you toggle `scaled` after deciding what to do.)

That means that for function like moveIt() nothing will happen the first time you tap the button. Rewrite that function like this:

```
func moveIt() {
    print("I like to moveIt moveIt!")
    self.moved.toggle() //Toggle the Bool first
    let newX: CGFloat = self.moved ? 0 : -50
    let newY: CGFloat = self.moved ? 0 : -150
    self.imageView.transform = self.imageView.transform.translatedBy(x: newX, y: newY)
}
```

Comment: Looks like it'd be useful to have in-place mutating variants of `inverted()`/`translatedBy(x:y:)`/`rotated(by:)`/`scaledBy(x:y:)`, perhaps `invert()`/`translate(x:y:)`/`rotate(by:)`/`scaleBy(x:y)`.

Comment: @DuncanC Thank you! You answered two questions, the one I was trying to ask (i.e. why is the scale operation rotating the figure?) and the one I didn't realize I needed to ask, (i.e. why are my transformations not stacking?). I would only quibble with your arithmetic: If I scale the figure by 1.5, then I need to scale it by 2/3 to get it back to the original size, not .5. That was a minor issue in a very clear answer to my question so, thanks, again.

Comment: True. If you are setting to explicit scales you'd want 1.5 and 0.5 as the values. I forgot to adjust the values if you're going to use them as mutipliers on an existing transform rather than explicit

Comment: I edited my answer. If it answered your question you should accept it. FYI, that is the expected behavior on this site.

Comment: Once you have enough reputation up-voting answers to your questions is optional, but good form if the answer was good. Up-voting other people's questions and answers is also good.

Comment: @Alexander I'm not sure you could have a mutating in-place function that would operate on the transform property of a view though, so most of the advantage of a mutating function is lost in this case.

Comment: It looks like there s a function `translateBy(x:y:)` in `CGContext`, but it applies the translation to the context's transform rather than to an arbitrary `CGAffineTransform`. It would be trivial to write an extension to `CGAffineTransform` that added those mutating functions.

Comment: @DuncanC An extension like that is exactly what I had in mind. It just down to `self = self.translatedBy(...)`

Comment: @Alexander if you write your own answer to the OP's question using an extension on `CGAffineTransform` I'd vote for it!

Comment: @DuncanC Meh, It's only a marginal improvement, I don't have the time to write that up now. Upvoted your answer though :)

Comment: @Alexander thanks for the thought, but are you sure about the up-vote? my vote count still shows as 0.

Comment: @DuncanC Huh, I could have sworn I did it. Fixed :)

Comment: You geezing? I'm the one with gray hair! :) Thanks for the vote.